# What is the file manager in this screenshot?

Tags: filemanager

Does anyone know the name of that file manager? Is it elementary Nautilus?

[image: http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2012/103/6/0/ayatana_scrollbar__by_kesymaru-d4w1rd1.png]

Comment: FYI: Nautilus-elementary was a patch for Nautilus 2, Marlin has it's design derived from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's `Marlin File Manager`. You can install this by adding the [marlin-daily ppa](https://launchpad.net/~marlin-devs/+archive/marlin-daily) to your system:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marlin-devs/marlin-daily
sudo apt-get update
```

and running `sudo apt-get install marlin marlin-plugin-*`.

Be warned, however, that this piece of software is not yet stable and is constantly being updated. It might suddenly break or crash your system if you try to use it. If you are not willing to take this risk then do not install or use marlin.

I do not know what theme is shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. I already have marlin installed but its looks kinda different from the one in the screenshot.

Comment: Marlin or the new Files (elementary file manager) above probably looks different from yours because of the theme used.